# GraphQL custom scalar type for HTML structure

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

During her brilliant presentation about scaling GraphQL, [Leanne Shapton](https://twitter.com/leeshapton) showed some best practices.

One of the most attractive for me was the custom scalar type for HTML structure. On the video it's [[10:16]](https://youtu.be/2It9NofBWYg?t=616)

She proposed using the custom `HTML` instead of simple `String`.
[image]

I wish you could show your implementation of this scalar or how do you handle these cases as I'm using only `String` for any HTML structure which doesn't seem to be a perfect way.

I'm asking not for creating scalar types or general information what is it scalar type and so on. Wondering if someone else has HTML handling already and does someone has any working solutions

Answer (score 2):

At a pure GraphQL level, the only thing you can (and must) do is include [a definition for the scalar type](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#scalar-types):

```graphql
scalar HTML
```

Once you done that, you can use it as a type as shown in the slide you cite.  In queries and results it will appear as some sort of scalar (string or numeric) value.

Different server and client libraries have different ways of dealing with this; there may be a uniform way to map a specific GraphQL scalar type to a native-language object.  In graphql-js, a [GraphQLScalarType object](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/type/#graphqlscalartype) takes `parseValue` and `serialize` functions to convert between the two representations, for example.  If you're just using a custom scalar type as a tagged string these can be very simple functions.

Comment: of course, David, thank you for the answer
but creating custom scalars wasn't an issue. What I'm asking is real-world implementations of this case which is quite widespread but still no modular solution.